# Which is better to use: $arrayName['literal'] or $arrayName[literal]?

Tags: php

Both are working fine. I'm just curious how php parse the two. Do they have difference on speed, efficiency, etc. Why does php allow us to use both?

Comment: check this out http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php

Comment: Turn on error reporting for an easy answer ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if you are using just `literal` php recognizes this as a [`constant`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.constants.php). So it try to find that constant, and if it fails - it just assumes that your desire was using string literal `'literal'`. But, to indicate that it doesn't found the constant it raises `Notice` level error.

So, using just `literal` have tweo drawbacks:

1. If you have constant `literal` defined - you'll get it's value (and this is a correct usage), not string `'literal'`
2. You'll receive a `Notice` if you don't have such constant.

So, don't use just `literal` unless you have a constant with that name defined.

Answer (score 3):

Difference is that the first ('literal') is a string key and that the second one is undefined constant. PHP allows you to use both because devs tried to fix bad code of people who weren't paying attention while reading the docs. There's a difference in speed since the second one will raise a warning - undefined constant. Basically, don't use the second one.

Answer (score 0):

$arrayName[literal] is bad because if you have constant named literal, you'll get unexpected results. When it's no constant named literal, php transforms literal to string 'literal'

Comment: just to confirm like what N.B. said the second one will raise a warning - undefined constant then php will transform the undefined constant to 'literal'? did i get it right?

Answer (score 0):

http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php

> **Array do's and don'ts**
>   **Why is $foo[bar] wrong?**
>
> Always use quotes around a string literal array index. For example,
>   $foo['bar'] is correct, while $foo[bar] is not. But why? It is common
>   to encounter this kind of syntax in old scripts:
>
> ```
> <?php
> $foo[bar] = 'enemy';
> echo $foo[bar];
> // etc
> ?>
> ```
>
> This is wrong, but it works. The reason is that this code has an
>   undefined constant (bar) rather than a string ('bar' - notice the quotes). PHP may in future define constants which, unfortunately for
>   such code, have the same name. It works because PHP automatically
>   converts a bare string (an unquoted string which does not correspond
>   to any known symbol) into a string which contains the bare string. For
>   instance, if there is no defined constant named bar, then PHP will
>   substitute in the string 'bar' and use that.